# Would getting a new Comcast modem change the WAN IP?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ip, modem, ipv4

Recently I've been getting ddosed because someone sent me a link which logged my IP. I've called Comcast and asked if they could change my ipv4 address and they only told me to do ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew in the command prompt. After being on the phone with them for a very long time, I decided to get a new modem. Would getting a new modem change my WAN IP?

Comment: It depends. Usually ISP's give business clients static IPs but not home clients. So, if you have a business class connection, most likely not. But, if you have a home connection, you will either get a new one when you plug in the new MODEM or a few days afterwards.

Comment: "Would getting a new modem change my WAN IP?" - Only Comcast can address this question.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a tricky question here, but here goes.

If you are a business account then no.  Business accounts are assigned static WAN IP's so no change in router/modem will alter this.

If you are a residential account if you want to change your WAN IP sometimes all you have to do is unplug your modem for 10 - 15 minutes and when you plug it back in the WAN IP has been recycled and you have a new WAN IP.

(Again for residential) If you have to call your ISP when you plug in your new modem and have your ISP provision it yes you definitely will get a new WAN IP.

Comment: Well, a technician from Comcast is coming out to install the new modem.

Comment: Would it be the same situation with a technician?

Comment: @Funk - Of course.  You don't even need a technician to do this.  They could have sent you the modem in the mail, or you could have picked it up, and called them up to provision the modem.  You are not going to get a new IP Address because you have a new modem.

Comment: @Funk - there is no installation required for a modem.  It is simply plug it in, then you can call customer service and have it provisioned on your own.

Comment: @user2676140 - So I won't be getting a new WAN IP? Is there any way of changing it if that is the case?

Comment: You could even call your ISP and ask them to assign you a new WAN IP.  A WAN IP is leased to you, in some instances a "break" in service (unplugging the modem) will release the lease.

Comment: @user2676140 I've asked for a new external ip address and most of the time they say they cannot, or they say I could get a static ip for extra money. I've restarted, unplugged, the modem multiple times for extended periods of time and the ip stays the same. I haven't used the term 'WAN' when I've called so maybe they will know what I'm talking about if I say that. Just to be sure, I would not get a new WAN ip address if I got a new modem? Because I already scheduled an appointment with a technician.

Comment: @Funk - Comcast only has so many IPv4 addresses.  They do not typically assign you a new address unless you have a valid reason.  Have you told them you believe you have been the victim of a DDOS attack?  It should be simple enough for them to confirm.  Please don't use the term "WAN ip address" that isn't the proper term, it is technically, not even a real term.

Answer (score 1):

If you can go in your router and change the MAC address, even by the one last digit, you will get a new IP address. This has to be the MAC on the WAN port that faces the comcast modem. Then suggest rebooting both comcast modem and router. This worked for me just this week. You do not need a whole new device (which would also work because it would be a new mac/hardware address) you just need to change your MAC.

Answer (score 0):

Ip addresses can be static (more expensive) or DHCP.
You probably have a DHCP address, look at your bill. 
DHCP servers assign IP addresses to MAC addresses. DHCP addresses usually do not change, because the lease is renewed, so you usually get the same one. If for some reason your device is offline for an etxtended period, the DHCP server can give way your IP, in which case you get another address.

I think that Comcast might even NAT addresses, this means that your IP is not public. So the public IP would be the IP of the device doing the Network Address Translation (NAT).
To find out if you are behind a NAT (running on a private Comcast Network) look at your IP address, and if it is a non routable ip address then your IP will be the one used by Comcast.
Google "non routable ip addresses" for a list.

hope this helps

Comment: How could you tell if your ip is a non routable ip? And if my ip is non routable is there any way of changing it? If I go to the router's page online I can see my WAN ip address listed.

Comment: Also, would getting a new modem change the WAN or non routable ip address?

Comment: @Funk - You will not get a new ip address assigned to you just because you have a new modem.

Comment: @Ramhound What can I do to change it then?

Comment: @Funk - Request your ISP provide you a new ip address, that might mean per their policy, you have to purchase a static ip address.